# thenThrow does not throw exception

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to write test case for a post controller. I want to mock an exception when a particular method is called inside the post controller. However, it does not work at all. The function gets executed and the test fails.

Test case:

```
    @Test(expected = ControllerException.class)
    public void testUpdateModelsSapFailure() throws Exception {
        String request = getUpdateModelsRequest(SKILL_ID, modelDefinition, SKILL_VERSION);

        // Make SAP call fail with an exception
        when(mockSapModelBuilder.buildDomainDefinition())
        .thenThrow(new ControllerException(org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,""));

        try {
            postController.updateApplicationModels(request, DEVELOPER);
        }
        finally {
            verifyModelIsNotSaved();
            verifyAmsIsNotCalledForUpdateSkill();
            verifyAmsIsNotCalledForEnableSkill();
        }
    }
```

Stacktrace:

```
Testcase: testUpdateModelsSapFailure(com.dew.controller.ManagementPostControllerTest):  Caused an ERROR
    [junit] Unexpected exception, expected<com.dew.exception.ControllerException> but was<org.mockito.exceptions.verification.NeverWantedButInvoked>
    [junit] java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected<com.dew.exception.ControllerException> but was<org.mockito.exceptions.verification.NeverWantedButInvoked>
    [junit]     at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.handleException(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:364)
    [junit]     at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.handleException(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
    [junit]     at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.handleInvocationTargetException(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:337)
    [junit]     at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:315)
    [junit]     at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
    [junit]     at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
    [junit]     at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    [junit]     at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
    [junit]     at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
    [junit]     at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
    [junit]     at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    [junit]     at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
    [junit]     at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:106)
    [junit]     at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    [junit]     at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    [junit] Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.verification.NeverWantedButInvoked: 
    [junit] aSKModelStorageClient.saveModelDefinition(
    [junit]     <any>,
    [junit]     <any>,
    [junit]     Development,
    [junit]     DewApplicationModelDefinition(models=domain definition, testCases=test cases, Calendars=[Calendar(name=CalendarName, entities=[CalendarEntity(value=CalendarValue)])]),
    [junit]     <any>
    [junit] );
    [junit] Never wanted here:
    [junit] -> at com.dew.controller.ManagementPostControllerTest.verifyModelIsNotSaved(ManagementPostControllerTest.java:1829)
    [junit] But invoked here:
    [junit] -> at com.dew.controller.ManagementPostController.updateApplicationModels(ManagementPostController.java:1250)
    [junit] 
    [junit]     at com.dew.controller.ManagementPostControllerTest.verifyModelIsNotSaved(ManagementPostControllerTest.java:1829)
    [junit]     at com.dew.controller.ManagementPostControllerTest.testUpdateModelsSapFailure(ManagementPostControllerTest.java:863)
    [junit]     at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
```

VerifyModelIsNotSaved:

```
private void verifyModelIsNotSaved() throws ModelException {
    verify(mockModelStorageClient, times(0)).saveModelDefinition(anyString(), anyString(),
            anyString(), eq(modelDefinition), anyString());
}
```

Comment: What's `verifyModelIsNotSaved`?

Comment: It checks if saveModelDefinition() function was called or not. That is what this test case should be able to verify. Ideally if buildDomainDefinition throws an exception then saveModelDefinition() should not be called.

Comment: Looks like `saveModelDefinition` was called, and the resulting exception from `verifyModelIsNotSaved` is interacting weirdly with the handling for the expected exception. I don't know whether it's supposed to display that way.

Comment: Is there anything wrong the way I have written theThrow statement? Also, mockSapModelBuilder is a mocked instance of a Builder class. Does that make any difference? Are we supposed to mock builders in a different way?

Comment: That `ControllerException` probably is getting thrown, but it's suppressed by the second exception during the `finally`.